# Django redirect to previous/current URL after LOGOUT

Tags: django, django-authentication

Although the question is simple I can't figure a way out to make this work.

I have many pages on a website and each page displays a button for the user to LOGOUT. If the user clicks on the button in some specific page the logout redirect should send them to the same page.

Since I'm using the `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'` in my `setting.py` the Logout buttons always redirects me to my home page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send a `next_url` attribute to the logout request which [Django LogoutView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LogoutView) uses to know to which page redirect after the logout. Something like:

```
<a href="{% url 'auth_logout' %}?next={{request.path}}"> Logout</a>
```